# Ruby problems with formotion module

Tags: iphone, ruby, xcode, rubymotion, formotion

There is an app written in ruby that I need to get running. It worked before IOS11 but is now throwing errors. I have formotion installed and all the appropriate gems and the SDK. I am having trouble getting the compiler to recognize that there is a formotion gem with things inside it.

I am getting an uncaught exception "Name Error" and it says that the variable im trying to instantiate within the formotion class is an uninitialized constant.

Any help with this error would be appreciated.

Here are some bit of the code, the error points to **`row.text_field.resignFirstResponder`**

```
module RowType
class PickerWithDoneRow < PickerRow
  include RowType::ItemsMapper

  def after_build(cell)
    super
    keyboardDoneButtonView              = UIToolbar.new
    keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle     = UIBarStyleBlack
    keyboardDoneButtonView.tintColor    = "#000".uicolor
    keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent  = false
    keyboardDoneButtonView.sizeToFit

    # keyboardDoneButtonView.barTintColor = "#BFC3C8".uicolor
    keyboardDoneButtonView.barTintColor = "#EFEFF4".uicolor

    doneButton = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithTitle("Done", style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain,  target:self, action: 'picker_done_clicked')
    spacer1    = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithBarButtonSystemItem(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace, target:self, action: nil)
    spacer     = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.initWithBarButtonSystemItem(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace, target:self, action: nil)
    keyboardDoneButtonView.setItems([spacer, spacer1, doneButton])

    row.text_field.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView
  end

  def picker_done_clicked

    row.text_field.resignFirstResponder
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Don’t use the preinstalled ruby, install any ruby version manager (e.g. http://rvm.io) and install the exact version of ruby you’ve used before OS update _within this package manager_.

Comment: I have done this. I am using RVM with 2.0.0-247. Also all the gems seem to be in place

Answer (score 0):

There were a few gems required for the program that were not included in the code as gems that needed to be installed. The gems needed were:

```
    bigdecimal (1.2.0)
  bubble-wrap (1.3.0)
  bundler (1.16.0)
  formotion (1.5.1)
  io-console (0.4.2)
  json (1.7.7)
  minitest (4.3.2)
  motion-csv (0.0.2)
  motion-require (0.0.7)
  motion-testflight (1.5)
  psych (2.0.0)
  rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6)
  rdoc (4.0.0)
  sugarcube (1.1.0)
  test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```